# create a Doubly LinkedList form a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I want to create a Doubly Linked list from list in python. The code is not working, can you please explain where I did the mistake.

Here's my code

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None
    self.prev = None


class DoublyList:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.head.next = self.head.prev = self.head
        self.size = 0

    for i in a:
        n = Node(i)
        if (self.head is None):
            self.head = n
            tail = n
        else:
            tail.next = n
            tail = n

def showList(self):
        current = self.head
        
        while current is not None:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.next
```

#### testing

```
lst = [10, 20, 30]
d = DoublyList(lst)
d.showList()
```

Comment: To help people zero in on an answer, it would be super helpful if you explained how it was "not working" and even provide an error message if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

this code should work, you didn't give self for tail and you need to check current next is None or not

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None


class DoublyList(Node):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.head = Node
        self.tail = Node
        self.head.next = self.head.prev = self.head
        self.size = 0

        for i in a:
            n = Node(i)
            if (self.head is None):
                self.head = n
                self.tail = n
            else:
                self.tail.next = n
                self.tail = n

    def showList(self):
        current = self.head
        
        while current.next is not None: 
            current = current.next
            print(current.data)
            
lst = [10, 20, 30]
d = DoublyList(lst)
d.showList()
```